# Error AL iniciar servidor Django

Tags: django, python-3.7

Estoy tratando de conectar django con una base de datos local mariadb

tengo esto instalado

```
PS C:\Django\sistema> pip3 list
Package      Version

asgiref      3.6.0
Django       4.2
django-mysql 4.9.0
mysqlclient  2.1.1
Pillow       9.5.0
pip          23.0.1
PyMySQL      1.0.3
setuptools   67.6.1
sqlparse     0.4.3
tzdata       2023.3
```

Pero cuando ejecuto el servidor python manage.py runserver, me sale este error.

```
PS C:\Django\sistema> python manage.py runserver     
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in 
_bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in 
run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
raise _exception[1]
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 394, in execute
autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
app_config.import_models()
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\apps\config.py", line 269, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 
126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 3, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 57, in <module>
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 143, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 371, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 243, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
conn = self.create_connection(alias)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\db\utils.py", line 193, in create_connection
backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\db\utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 
126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 35, in <module>
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.4.3 or newer is required; you have 
1.0.3.
```

tengo esta configuracion

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': "django.db.backends.mysql",
        'NAME': "libreria",
        'USER': "root",
        'PASSWORD': "",
        'HOST': "localhost",
        'PORT': "3307"
    }
}
```

En el archivo **init**.py

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Esto es lo que me indica chatGPT pero tampoco funciona

El error parece ser causado por un problema con la base de datos. La última línea del error sugiere que hay un problema al intentar cargar el backend de la base de datos, posiblemente debido a un problema de configuración en el archivo settings.py.

Aquí hay algunas posibles soluciones que podrían ayudar:

Verifique que la configuración de la base de datos en su archivo settings.py sea correcta y que todas las claves y valores estén escritos correctamente. Verifique también que esté utilizando el controlador de base de datos correcto y que haya instalado los paquetes necesarios.

Asegúrese de que la base de datos esté en funcionamiento y accesible. Intente conectarse a la base de datos desde la línea de comandos para asegurarse de que la conexión funcione.

Intente eliminar los archivos de caché de Django y vuelva a ejecutar el servidor. Ejecute el comando python manage.py clear_cache para eliminar los archivos de caché.

Si está utilizando un entorno virtual, asegúrese de que el entorno virtual esté activado y que esté ejecutando el comando desde el directorio correcto.

Si ninguno de estos pasos resuelve el problema, puede proporcionar más detalles sobre su configuración y el código que está ejecutando para obtener una ayuda más precisa.

Comment: Es por esto que no tenés que usar ChatGPT (para obtener código) si no entendés qué estás haciendo. Tal chat es ambiguo y puede proporcionarte código de librerías desfasadas. Por cierto, leé la última línea del error: tal vez allí estés teniendo una pista enorme ;)

Comment: La última línea del error te lo dice claramente: la versión de PyMySQL que tienes instalada (1.0.3) parece que no es compatible con tu versión de Django. Por cierto, has probado a usar mysqlclient en vez de PyMySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Me pasaba igual solo actualiza el conector por este:

pip installl mysqlclient

En el archivo init.py

import pymysql
pymysql.version_info = (2, 1, 1, "final", 0)